# Making circles using Kinectjs

Tags: kineticjs

I am having a ton of problems trying to create a circle on a Kinetic layer. Basically I am trying to create a painting application but I figure I need to tackle this problem one step at a time. So I just want to be able to literally drag and drop a circle. I have something but I know it is absolutely riddled with errors. Please, I really really need some guidance, I have not used KineticJs or javascript for a very long time, so I really want to understand how this all works. Thank you and have a good day!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta chartset="utf-8">
    <title>Creating a Cirlce</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var stage = new Kinectic.Stage({
                container: "container",
                width: 400,
                height: 400
            });

            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

            background = new Kinetic.Rect({
                x: 0, 
                y: 0, 
                width: stage.getWidth(),
                height: stage.getHeight(),
                fill: "white"
            });

            var Circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                radius: 0,
                fill: "red",
                stroke: "black",
                strokeWidth: 4
            });

            layer.add(background);
            layer.add(Circle);
            stage.add(layer);

            var moving = false;

            stage.on("mousedown", function(){
                if (moving) {
                    moving = false;
                    layer.draw();
                }
                else {
                    var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
                    moving = true;
                    Circle.x = pos.x;
                    Circle.y = pos.y
                    Circle.radius = 0;
                    layer.drawScene();

                }
            });

            stage.on("mousemove", function(){
                if (moving) {
                    var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
                    var x = pos.x;
                    var y = pos.y;
                    Circle.x = pos.x;
                    Cirlce.y = pos.y;
                    Cirlce.radius = 0.5 * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2)+Math.pow(y,2));
                    Cirlce.fill = "red";
                    Circle.stroke = "black";
                    Cirlce.strokeWidth = 1;
                }
            });

            stage.on("mouseup", function() {
                moving = false;
            })
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here’s how to dynamically sketch a KineticJS circle using mouse events**

On mousedown:  set the centerpoint of the circle and turn on the moving flag.

```
var moving = false;
var startX;
var startY;

// mousedown sets the centerpoint of the circle (startX/startY)
// and turns on the moving flag

stage.on("mousedown", function(){
    var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
    startX=pos.x;
    startY=pos.y;
    layer.drawScene();
    moving=true;
});
```

On mouseup:  turn off the moving flag.

```
stage.on("mouseup", function() {
    moving = false;
})
```

On mousemove: dynamically extends the circle from the centerpoint to the current mouse position

```
// mousemove dynamically extends the circle from the centerpoint (startX/startY)
// with a radius extending to the current mouse position

stage.on("mousemove", function(){

    if(!moving){return;}

    var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
    var x = pos.x;
    var y = pos.y;
    dx=x-startX;
    dy=y-startY
    var radius=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy); 
    circle.setX(startX);
    circle.setY(startY);
    circle.setRadius(radius);
    circle.fill = "red";
    circle.stroke = "black";
    circle.strokeWidth = 1;
    layer.drawScene();
});
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/43Kmg/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #container{border:1px solid red; width:400px;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: "container",
            width: 400,
            height: 400
        });

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        stage.add(layer);


        var background = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: 0, 
            y: 0, 
            width: stage.getWidth(),
            height: stage.getHeight(),
            fill: "white"
        });
        layer.add(background);


        var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
          y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
          radius: 5,
          fill: 'red',
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 2
        });
        layer.add(circle);

        layer.draw();


        var moving = false;
        var startX;
        var startY;

        // mousedown sets the centerpoint of the circle
        // and turns on the moving flag

        stage.on("mousedown", function(){
            var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
            startX=pos.x;
            startY=pos.y;
            layer.drawScene();
            moving=true;
        });

        // mousemove draws a circle from the centerpoint (that was set in mousedown)
        // with a radius extending to the current mouse position

        stage.on("mousemove", function(){

            if(!moving){return;}

            var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
            var x = pos.x;
            var y = pos.y;
            dx=x-startX;
            dy=y-startY
            var radius=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy); 
            circle.setX(startX);
            circle.setY(startY);
            circle.setRadius(radius);
            circle.fill = "red";
            circle.stroke = "black";
            circle.strokeWidth = 1;
            layer.drawScene();
        });

        // mouseup turns off the moving flag

        stage.on("mouseup", function() {
            moving = false;
        })


    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @CoryGross Thanks, I forgot the previous KineticJS and Chrome had a problem with fills causing failure.  I put the latest KineticJS on the fiddle and it should be working now.   Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score -2):

Please, look at tutorial on KineticJS official site.
[Circle](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-circle-tutorial/), [Drag and Drop](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @Razum but this isn't what I want. I want to literally create a shape with my cursor, for instance a circle or a line or a rectangle. This was created just for a circle. I just don't see how this tutorial is going to help me.